# ¿Cómo encapsular o aislar funciones (o librerías) para que no colisionen con otras funciones idénticas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Es complejo de explicar asi que intentaré expresarme de la mejor forma posible, ya que ésto precisa de un mínimo de información.

Es una herramienta de autor, un poco distinta a trabajar con un 'index.html' por ejemplo, y consta de una 'página' (que es un `iframe`) o múltiples páginas (se pasa de una a otra con un click en un Nav) y en ella sacamos módulos, que son interactivos.

Esta es una imagen final de cómo queda visto desde un navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada módulo es independiente, tiene su `HTML` (divisiones, etiquetas, clases...) y su código `Javascript` en él. Esta forma de trabajar es la que lo hace peculiar. Las funciones no están en ningún caso al principio o final del `HTML`. Además si sacara 2 módulos idénticos aunque tengan un contenido distinto, por ejemplo los módulos 1 y 2 de la imagen, tendríamos 2 veces repetido el código. Son como... pequeñas aplicaciones dentro de un HTML con su funcionalidad.

Como os figuraréis no colisionan ni se comunican entre sí a menos que nosotros se lo digamos en código (salvo clases y estilos `CSS` e identificadores, esos si se 'ven'). La propagación está bastante controlada por este motivo.

Una de las limitaciones, es que sólo tiene jQuery 1.7.1 y no se puede actualizar para todo el documento, sólo puedo cargarla dinámicamente en cada módulo que sus librerias requieran una versión superior, y aplicar un `callback()` y hacer algo. Este es el código que alberga un módulo como los 1 y 2 de la imagen:

```
function modulo_crear() {

    var esteModulo = function () { };

    /************************** INICIO ***********************************/
    /*Objeto donde irá la aplicación. Consta de 2 librerías como requisito. jQuery 1.12. 
Una vez cargado ésto, ejecutamos la función para que muestre la información recopilada.*/

    var mappSpace = {};

    mappSpace = function (argumentos) {

        //Función carga de librería Jquery vía dinámica.
        function loadScript(url, callback) {

            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.id = 'jquery-loaded';

            if (script.readyState) { //IE
                script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        callback();
                    }
                };
            } else {
                script.onload = function () {
                    callback();
                };
            }

            script.src = url;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        }


        //Función (¿objeto?) donde están las dos librerías que necesita el módulo.
        var mainLibs = function ($) {

            var libreria1 = function (argumento) {
                //Aquí va el código de la librería 1.
            };


            (function (argumento) {
                //Aquí va la segunda librería
            }(function ($) {

            }));
        };



        var imageArray = [];
        var imageIdArray = [];

        // Metemos en los arrays los datos que se meten desde la plataforma. (imágenes e identificadores).
        for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
            imageArray.push(imgArray[i].imgUnit);
            imageIdArray.push(imgArray[i].imgId);
        }


        // Cargamos la nueva versión de jQuery que necesita y usamos el callback.
        loadScript(newjQuery, function () {

            // Reemplazo $ por $N para que la librería tome lo que necesite.
            var $N = $.noConflict();
            mainLibs($N);

            $N('#container').libreria1({
                // Opciones Librería 1
            });

            /* Eliminamos la ruta de la librería JQuery del head que acabamos de cargar. 
Se hace ésto porque tener dos o más modulos idénticos, implica que cargará dos o más veces todo éste código.*/
                let checkLib = document.getElementById('jquery-loaded');
                if (checkLib) {
                    document.head.removeChild(checkLib);
                }
            });
        }
        /***************************** FIN *************************************/






    // Al cargar la página HTML, esta función ejecuta todo lo demás, es la que inicia.
    esteModulo.start = function (argumentos) {
        mappSpace();
    }



    /* Componentes ajenos a lo que tratamos arriba, esto es parte de la plataforma, recopila 
datos, etc, pero no interfiere.*/
        esteModulo.controlador = function () {

    };

    esteModulo.comandos = function () {

    };

    esteModulo.visibilidad = function () {

    };

    esteModulo.mostrar = function () {

    };

    esteModulo.ocultar = function () {

    };

    return esteModulo;

}
```

El código que está entre los asteriscos, es el que tengo que hacer funcionar, el resto, son las herramientas que aparecen en cada módulo, no afectan. Ahora mismo si tengo dos o más módulos no colisionan y en términos generales funciona todo, pero el problema radica en la librería `jQuery` cargada, que altera el funcionamiento de otros módulos. Por ejemplo el `div` con la imagen del retrato, es `draggable` y al tener éste módulo presente, ha dejado de funcionar. Con otros módulos sucede de forma similar.

Ahora sabemos con qué contamos y que limitantes tenemos. El problema por tanto está en que el `jQuery` que cargo dinámicamente, no está encapsulado y supongo que es porque lo envío al`HEAD` por lo que afecta a todo.

Entonces, ¿hay que encapsularlo? ¿Existe algún método para casos muy concretos como éste?, ¿El código que he puesto entre los asteriscos, está bien ecapsulado?. Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, he dado con el problema. Las dos versiones de jQuery estaban bien cargadas pero había funciones dentro del plugin que afectaban al documento general.

```
$(document).ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
};
```

Con razón no funcionaba la función draggable en toda la página jeje.

Cosas como identificadores, document, window, etc si que afectan a todo y todos pese a estar encerrado en un módulo. Lección aprendida, gracias igualmente :).

Comment: También es buena práctica utilizar let y const. Éstas hacen que el scope de la variable no se haga global.

Comment: Puedes marcar como respuesta aceptada tu misma respuesta para que el sistema no la relance cada cierto tiempo.